# I am trying to run a Python script through Java, but I want to run the import lines in Python only once

Tags: python, java, processbuilder

I am trying to run a Python script through Java, but I want to run the import lines in Python only once since I am importing TensorFlow and spaCy in my Python script. Importing them takes time, so I don't want to run the whole script again and again through Java. Is there any way to do that?

Here is my Python code. This is just example code since I am working on this problem

```py
import sys

while True:
    # read input from standard input
    
    input_str = input()

    # process the input
    output_str = "Processed input: " + input_str

    # write output to standard output
    print(output_str)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and here is my java code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class RunPythonScriptInteractive {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Start the Python process
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            Map env = builder.environment();
            env.put("PATH", env.get("PATH") + ":/home/parth/miniconda3/bin");
            builder.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "python pythontry.py");

            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = builder.start();
            Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            BufferedWriter outputWriter = process.outputWriter();
            BufferedReader reader = process.inputReader();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                String input = cin.nextLine();
                
                outputWriter.write(input);
                outputWriter.newLine();
                outputWriter.flush();

                Stream<String> lines = reader.lines();

                lines.forEach(System.out::println);
            }
            
            outputWriter.close();
            reader.close();

            process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to give input through my Java code three times to my Python script, but it is not working.

I expect that if I give input three times from my Java code, I get output three times from my Python script like:

```
hello
Processed input: hello

world
Processed input: world

nice
Processed input: nice
```

Comment: The problem is how you read input from the Python process in Java, this will block until the end of stream is reached (which only happens when the process ends), so it never reaches the second iteration of the loop. You need to offload this to a separate thread.

Comment: can you please give an example through code
i have also tried the while method to print lines but it still did not work
yes i am experiencing the problem you described i tried printing some random stuff after the forEach line but it didn't run and i am in an infinite loop

```
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null || line.equals(""))
    {
     System.out.println(line);
    }
    outputWriter.close();
    reader.close();
```

Comment: the `while True` in python will run forever as it has no exit. is this what you wanted ?

Comment: yes the aim is to keep the python script running and i will give inputs from java and get output if the python script will end i will have to rerun it means all the imports have to be made again which i am trying to avoid

Comment: The line `lines.forEach(System.out::println);` runs until sub-process exits, so it needs to be in different thread.

Comment: can you please give example with code thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution here's the python code

```
import sys

while True:
    # read input from standard input
    input_str = input()

    # process the input
    output_str = "Processed input: " + input_str

    # write output to standard output
    print(output_str)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

in java we have to create 2 classes one for giving input and another class for reading the output we will have to use multi-threading one thread to give input to the script and the other thread to read output from the script.

here is the Main class which will give input to the script and will return the final output.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process process = null;
        String output="";
        ThreadClass thread = null;
        try {
            
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            Map env = builder.environment();
            env.put("PATH", env.get("PATH") + ":/home/parth/miniconda3/bin");
            builder.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "python pythontry.py");
            process = builder.start();
            
            Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
            BufferedWriter outputWriter = process.outputWriter();
            thread = new ThreadClass(process);
            thread.start();
            
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                String input = cin.nextLine();
                outputWriter.write(input);
                outputWriter.newLine();
                outputWriter.flush();
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            process.destroy();
            output = thread.getOutput();
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the second thread class that will read output of the python script

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class ThreadClass extends Thread {
    
    Process process;
    String output;
    
    public ThreadClass(Process process) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.process = process;
        output="";
    }
    
    public void readOutputFromScript() throws IOException {
        try{
            
            BufferedReader reader = process.inputReader();
            String line;
            
            while(true)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(line==null || line.equals(""))
                {
                    break;
                }
                output+=line;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            readOutputFromScript();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
    public String getOutput()
    {
        return output;
    }
}
```

**My gratitude to all my friends who helped me reach this solution**